# Converting CNContact to NSData and vice versa

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, multipeer-connectivity, cncontact

I'm trying to convert `CNContact` objects into NSData to be sent to another device over Multipeer Connectivity. Here's my code for sending the contacts data:

```
 func sendContactsToPeer(peerId: MCPeerID, contacts: [CNContact]) {
    let contactsData: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(contacts)
    do {
        try self.session.sendData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(contactsData), toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
    } catch {
        print("Unable to send contacts data to \(peerId.displayName)")
    }
}
```

And this is for receiving contacts:

```
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    print("Received data: \(data) From Peer: \(peerID)")

    if let contacts: [CNContact] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? [CNContact] {
        self.delegate?.didReceiveContacts(contacts, fromPeer: peerID)
    }
}
```

There is output for the print statement for the `NSData`, which indicates that the data is not nil. But when I tried unarchiving the object into an array of CNContacts, it returns nil. Any ideas why?

Note that I've also tried just sending a single `CNContact` object instead of an array of them, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I've accidentally archive the `CNContact` data twice in the code above, and for unarchiving I've only did it once. Changing the code for unarchiving the the one below works:

```
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    print("Received data: \(data) From Peer: \(peerID)")

    if let contactsData: NSData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? NSData {
        if let contacts: [CNContact] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(contactsData) as? [CNContact] {
            self.delegate?.didReceiveContacts(contacts, fromPeer: peerID)
        }
    }
}
```

But however if I only archive the `CNContact` object once and unarchiving it, it doesn't work. Still have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Check out CNContactVCardSerialization class